# Can you keyframe effects in grease pencil? If so how?

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil, effects, 2d

Im creating a fire animation in blender grease pencil. I added glow and transparency effects. In certain parts of my animation it would make sense for glow and transparency to get stronger/weaker. Is it possible to keyframe effects (from the visual effects tab in properties if your lost) and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are dots beside most of the fields in effects, just like in modifiers. Clicking on the dot will insert a keyframe for that property.

Also hovering over the field and pressing `I` also inserts a keyframe for the value. This works in shaders too.

[image]